# Conditional statement does not trigger my animation when using the next button if the condition is the same as the preceding condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Hope someone can help. Bit difficult to explain but I have just finished and submitted my code for a challenge and although I met the basic requirements for the challenge, I decided to add an animation as a little extra.

We were given some code that randomly generated a new set of numbers within arrays every-time the browser window was refreshed. My job was to total up the numbers in the array and build an app which used a next and previous button to iterate through the arrays. The buttons triggered a condition, if the total amount of money was > than the given price of something (true) then a message should display something like "you can afford" else (false) "you can't afford.

If you clicked previous or next it iterated back and forth through the random generated array. eg if I clicked next it would generate a new set of random numbers and as a result a new total and either true or false against the condition.

I added an animation into the mix to be triggered by the above condition so if it displayed "you can afford" the animation is added and run and removed "if you can't afford".

The code works if I hit next and have a true condition preceding a false condition and vice vera.

However if I have a true condition following another true condition after clicking next then the animation only runs on the first true condition.

I hope that makes sense and here is my code. Apologies for the amount of code but I think it explains it a bit better. Much appreciated.

```
function roll(min, max, floatFlag) {
  let r = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  return floatFlag ? r : Math.floor(r);
}

let testPurses = Array(5)
  .fill(0)
  .map((a) => {
    return {
      quarters: roll(0, 15),
      dimes: roll(0, 30),
      nickels: roll(0, 40),
      pennies: roll(0, 50),
      price: Number(roll(0, 10, 1).toFixed(2))
    };
  });
/* 
    Write a function enoughChange
    
    Given an object representing a coin purse, and a price
        it should return true/false depending on whether 
        or not you have enough change to complete a 
        purchase at the given price
    
    The function should also update the "counters"
        such that they reflect the quantities in
        the test case
        
    You should then use this function to update the 
        purchaseConfirmation div to display whether
        or not you can afford the purchase with the
        coin quantities provided
        
    Finally, create nextCase and previousCase 
        buttons to cycle through the test cases 
    
    Refresh the mini-browser or save this file to
        load new test cases!
*/

const purchaseConfirmation = document.getElementById("purchase-confirmation");
const quarterCounter = document.getElementById("quarter-count");
const dimeCounter = document.getElementById("dime-count");
const nickelCounter = document.getElementById("nickel-count");
const pennyCounter = document.getElementById("penny-count");
const nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-case");
const prevBtn = document.getElementById("previous-case");
const reload = document.getElementById("reloadBTN");
const purchaseConfirm = document.getElementById("purchase-confirmation");
const plane = document.querySelector(".plane");

let index = 0;

const handleChanges = () => {
  let { quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies } = testPurses[index];
  const coinCount = Object.values(testPurses[index]);
  let Moneytotal = (
    coinCount[0] * 1 +
    coinCount[1] * 5 +
    coinCount[2] * 10 +
    coinCount[3] * 20
  ).toFixed(2);
  let itemPrice = (testPurses[index].price * 100).toFixed(2);
  let leftover = (Moneytotal - itemPrice).toFixed(2);
  quarterCounter.innerHTML = quarters;
  dimeCounter.innerHTML = dimes;
  nickelCounter.innerHTML = nickels;
  pennyCounter.innerHTML = pennies;

  let enough = `Yeeesssss... you did it.You have saved £${Moneytotal} and can afford a post lock-down holiday worth £${itemPrice} with £${leftover}  left over, for going crazy with `;

  let notEnough = `Sorry you can't afford a holiday any time soon.. keep your chin up and keep saving`;

  if (Moneytotal >= itemPrice) {
    purchaseConfirm.innerHTML = enough;
    plane.classList.add("animation");
  } else {
    purchaseConfirm.innerHTML = notEnough;
    plane.classList.remove("animation");
  }
};

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (index >= 0 && index < testPurses.length - 1) {
    index++;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }

  handleChanges();
});

reload.addEventListener("click", () => {
  history.go(0);
});

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (index >= 1) {
    index--;
  } else {
    index = testPurses.length - 1;
  }

  handleChanges();
});

handleChanges();
```

CSS below:

```
.animation{
  
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  /* animation-play-state: paused;   */
 

}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  
  }

  to {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="coins">
      <div class="coin quarter">£1</div>
      <div class="coin dime">£5</div>
      <div class="coin nickel">£10</div>
      <div class="coin penny">£20</div>
    </div>

    <div id="coin-counts">
      <div id="quarter-count"></div>
      <div id="dime-count"></div>
      <div id="nickel-count"></div>
      <div id="penny-count"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="purchase-confirmation"></div>
    <div id="fly"><img class="plane" src="https://epixieme.github.io/images-repo/planesmall.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="case-switcher">
      <button id="previous-case">Previous</button>
      <button id="reloadBTN">Reload Sequence</button>
      <button id="next-case">Next</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- <a href="https://www.vecteezy.com/"> PNGs by Vecteezy</a>  -->
  <script src="index.pack.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeah the challenge really helped me as someone who is learning. You can get the challenges by signing up to Scrimba and you get a different one every week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to see your CSS

But my initial thought is that you need to remove the 'animation' class before you add it to get the animation to play again. The class is already added on a 'true' case so you just add it again. As the animation has already played it won't play it again. This is why when the conditions aren't the same, it works as you are adding and removing the class as necessary

```
plane.classList.remove("animation");
```

Full example of the if condition:

```
plane.classList.remove("animation");
if (Moneytotal >= itemPrice) {
    purchaseConfirm.innerHTML = enough;
    plane.classList.add("animation");
  } else {
    purchaseConfirm.innerHTML = notEnough;
    
  }
```

The remove and add of the class is happening to quickly so try wrapping your callback in a timeout as follows

```
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (index >= 0 && index < testPurses.length - 1) {
    index++;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
 plane.classList.remove("animation");
  window.setTimeout(()=>{handleChanges();}, 500)
  //handleChanges();
});
```

Alternatively, you could actually just add an eventlistener for the animationend event and remove the class there:

e.g

```
 plane.addEventListener('animationend', () => {

  plane.classList.remove('animation')
})
```

Comment: No it didn't work :-( good point about the CSS. I'll update the question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Interesting, as in a scaled back example, removing the class and then adding it again does trigger the animation as you can see here https://jsbin.com/boyahuhehu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: It's really strange isn't it. It triggers the animation if next button is clicked and the condition is "true - add animation" and then the next button is clicked again and this time the condition is  "false - remove animation".  But not  the next button is clicked and if its true - add animation and clicked again and condition is again  true-add animation.  Not sure how to get round it.

Comment: Can you share the html as well or make your code runnable within stackoverflow? I'm not sure if the top of your JS code has been cutoff as well as there is a stray closing brace

Comment: Sorry was just my back ticks were in the wrong place so it cut off the top. :-) Thanks for taking a look, I've added the full HTML.

Comment: I think the issue is the remove and add happens too quickly, wrap your call to handleChanges in a timeout like the updated example which you can also view here  https://jsbin.com/juqajavujo/edit?html,css,js,output (note I've made it so it always says you have enough money to test)

Comment: You can also use an `animationend` event listener. Though if the person presses next too quickly if might not be the effect you're after. However it might be just what you want as the animation just continues to play. Again I've added this to the answer

Comment: ooh thanks so much, I'll have a go with that later on . I did wonder if it was all happening a bit too fast .. I'll have a go and report back.

Comment: Thank you so much you're a star. The animationend worked. I'll have a go with delaying  the handleChanges slightly also.